# Parse xml by Xdocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have a simple xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <Parameters>
        <Valid>
          <SetSensorParameter>
            <param paramid="1" value_p="15" size="16"/>
            <param paramid="2" value_p="22" size="8"/>
          </SetSensorParameter>
       </Valid>
     </Parameters>
```

I need get values of attributes of :

```
    <param paramid="1" value_p="15" size="16"/>
    <param paramid="2" value_p="22" size="8"/>
```

I have next code for it:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    var smth = doc.Element("Parameters").Element("Valid").Element("SetSensorParameter").Nodes();
```

I get access to both *param*, but i can't get values of *paramid, 
value_p, size*.

How I can do it?

Comment: try XElement.attribute("value_p")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get attribute values this way:

```
var attributes =  doc.Root.Descendants()
                     .Where(elem => elem.HasAttributes)
                     .SelectMany(e => e.Attributes());

foreach (var attr in attributes)
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, value: {1}", attr.Name, attr.Value);
```

Comment: Thank You. doc.Root.Element("Valid").Element("SetSensorParameter").Descendants()... is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `Nodes`, it would be simpler to use `Elements`, so that you can then use the `Attribute` method to retrieve each attribute:

```
var parameters = doc.Root
                    .Element("Valid")
                    .Element("SetSensorParameters")
                    .Elements("param");

foreach (var parameter in parameters)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}",
                      (int) parameter.Attribute("paramid"),
                      (int) parameter.Attribute("value_p"),
                      (int) parameter.Attribute("size"));
}
```

Here the casts parse each of those attribute values as an `int`; similar conversions are available for other types.

Comment: Visual studio told me, that it is not possible, because XElement doesn't have public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Comment: @Imorian I assume you've fixed spelling mistake by Jon Skeet wrong way... I've updated the post - should be good now.

Comment: Course, i fix it at once. But it is not a problem. I can't get enumerator for "parameters", and can't use foreach for it.

Comment: @Imorian: The fixed code compiles perfectly for me - copied and pasted. If you hover over the `var` of `var parameters` what does it show? Are you sure you've got `Elements` as the last method call, not `Element`? (As Alexei suggested, my thought is that you fixed my typo by *removing* the `s` instead of just putting it in the right place.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var parameters = doc.Root
                .Element("Valid")
                .Element("SetSensorParameter")
                .Element("param");
```

I can use just

```
     var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var parameters = doc.Root
                .Element("Valid")
                .Element("SetSensorParameter")
                .Element("param").Attributes();
```

And after that

```
    parameters.ElementsAfterSelf.Attributes();
```

Sorry but my Visual Studio don't want to make foreach with parameters.